# Firebase once() timeout

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase `once()` method to retrieve a value in a React Native mobile app. Trouble is if the phone is offline, `once()` never returns. Documentation says that `ref.off()` method should cancel callbacks, but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm guessing that `off()` doesn't apply to `once()` callbacks. If so how would I create a timeout?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion but this is not a debugging help question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such concept as a timeout when dealing with Firebase Realtime Database APIs on any platform.  Clients are generally not expected to know or care if they're online or offline, except by [querying a special location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) that indicates as such.

If you want to implement your own timeout for a query (for the web), use `setTimeout` to force some code to execute after some amount of time.  You'll have to be careful to coordinate between your database callback and the `setTimeout` callback such that if one triggers, the other one does not.

Comment: The link you sent is very useful -- many thanks! As to creating custom timeout, I was thinking along the same lines (setTimout), however what would I call on timeout? ref.off() would be perfect, otherwise I don't know how to cancel the Firebase request.