# React: timeout call to Firebase

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm using React with Firebase and I want to handle the call when there is too much time in pending with an error message.
This is my call to database

```
fire.database().ref('user/').once('value')
.then(function(result){
    /* MY CODE */
})
```

Thanks so much for your collaboration

Comment: This seems highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805031/firebase-once-timeout

Comment: Do you mean you call this, after some time of use inactivity? like after an ideal time of 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing handler by using `setTimeout`:

```
let rejectTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    /*SHOW ERROR MESSAGE*/
  clearTimeout(rejectTimeout);
  rejectTimeout = null;
}, 1 * 60 * 1000); //1 minute

fire.database().ref('user/').once('value')
.then(function(result){
    /* MY CODE */
    if (rejectTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(rejectTimeout);
      rejectTimeout = null;
    } else {
      /* HANDLE CASE RECEIVE RESPONSE AFTER REJECT */
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.